# удаление элемента из массива c++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Функция удаляет из массива нужный элемент по индексу.

```
bool del(int *arr, int &length, int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index > length) 
        return false;

    for (int i = index; i < length; i++) 
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i+1]; 
    }
    length--; 
    return true;
}
```

**Вопрос:** допустим есть массив `arr[3] = {1,2,3}` и нужно удалить элемент под 
индексом 2 (элемент равный 3)

Тогда в функции запустится такой код:

```
arr[2] = arr[3]
```

а что хранится то в этом arr[3]?

Программа на это не ругается и адекватно удаляет нужный мне индекс и в итоге получается массив {1,2}

Answer (score 2):

Хранится неизвестно что.
Которое вообще-то трогать не рекомендуется.

Вам надо просто при `index == length-1` делать `--length` и все.

Или переписать цикл как

```
for (int i = index+1; i<length; i++) 
{
    arr[i-1] = arr[i]; 
}
```

Comment: как вы пришли к такой логике? я никогда в жизни бы наверно не додумался до этого. какими знаниями вы оперировали или простой банальный опыт?

Comment: По-моему, очевидно. Понятно, что arr[3] - за пределами. Написал первое предложение. Далее, что вы делаете? Смещаете все влево и говорите, что длина на 1 меньше - т.е. что **за пределами** длины, нас не колышет. Т.е. последний элемент автоматом будет отброшен. Так что если удалять его - то вообще ничего не надо. Так, написал второе предложение :) Посмотрел на цикл - нам надо перемещать до последнего элемента, но не его. Подправил цикл, дописал ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Будет неопределенное поведение программы. Имейте в виду, что в вашу функцию могут передать массив, который был размещен в динамической памяти, и в таком случае, когда происходит обращение к памяти за пределами массива, программа даже может завершиться аварийно.

У функции есть несколько недостатков помимо обращения за пределы массива. У нее сложный интерфейс. К тому же индексы имеют тип `int`., тогда как, например, оператор `sizeof` возвращает объекты типа `size_t`. Поэтому будет лучше объявить индекс и размер массива, как имеющие тип `size_t`.

Функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
bool del( int *a, size_t n, size_t i )
{
    bool success;

    if ( ( success = i < n ) )
    {
        while ( ++i < n ) a[i-1] = a[i];
    }

    return success;
}
```

Функция могла бы быть вызвана следующим образом

```
if ( del( arr, length, index ) ) --length;
```

Или, к примеру

```
size_t n = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
n -= del( arr, n, index );
```